# NSMutableArray Datasrouce TableView UI Freeze after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing for iOS 10 with XCode Version 8.0.

in my .h file, I have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;
```

which is the datasource for my TableView.

in viewDidLoad, I call my function [self setupTableViewItems];

```
self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
self.items = [CellModel rows];
```

Every object inside of this array is representing my cells, example:

```
CellModel *screenshot = [[CellModel alloc]
                            initWithParams:         @"Screenshot"
                            subTitle:               @"Select a screenshot"
                            image:                  [UIImage imageNamed: @"screenshot"]
                            viewName:               Pictures
                            section:                3];
```

here is the method signature,

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)rows;
```

and the important implementations details (every object is of type CellModel):

```
NSMutableArray *screenshots = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
[screenshots addObject:quickScreenshot];
[screenshots addObject:selectScreenshot];
[screenshots addObject:selectedScreenshotsCollectionView];
```

.....

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
[dataSource addObject:interactions];
[dataSource addObject:screenshots];
[dataSource addObject:problem];
[dataSource addObject:details];

return [dataSource mutableCopy];
```

The tableView loads the data correctly for the first time, the view looks great and nothing is missing.

When I start scrolling, I immidetely notice that the accessoryviews for the cells start getting mixed up, especially on section 3, where they are defined to NOT have an acessory view, but still gets mixed up and get other cell's accessory views.

However, as soon as the orientation changes, or I start scrolling up and down a few times, the UI is locked, no crash, no message from XCode. Memory is growing and this is obviously a leak, but after trying to find it for hours, I am desperate.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
GenericTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REPORT_CELL
                                  forIndexPath: indexPath];

CellModel *current = [[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.titleLabel.text = current.title;
cell.subtitleLabel.text = current.subTitle;
cell.icon.image = current.image;

    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.accessoryView = self.lastInteractionSwitch;
    else if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.accessoryView = self.lastScreenshotSwitch;
    else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    else if(indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.accessoryView = self.starRatingView;
    else if(indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1)
        cell.accessoryView = self.speechToTextButton;
    else cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
return cell;
```

My custom cell has three properties, the ones that are being set. The custom cell is of type "Subtitle", and the properties are connected in IB.

First, I thought it was because I didn't have a pointer reference, added it, tried with the intiutive and obvious ones (strong || retain), moved on to having an NSArray as datasource, same problem. Changed the cell (to 100% apple, 100% custom), same problem.

What is happening here?

Comment: You mention that the accessory view is what's getting messed up, but I don't see you setting the accessory anywhere in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on your dequeued cells. Are you setting this property anywhere before displaying the cell? Also, is the table (and its cells) the only UI element on the screen?

Comment: Yes, it is. I updated my cellForRowAtIndexPath: definition for you. I change the navigationbar´s barTintColor, set it to translucent, set the text to white, and add a rightbutton item. Other than that, I am simply presenting a tableview, nothing else.

Comment: UI locked and memory grows = you have infinite recursion/loop on main thread (likely). Run it with debugger and when it happens - just press pause in the debugger. If you're not stopped in your code - do it a couple of times. Any luck?

Comment: Ain't no recursions happening on my behalf, homeboy ;). Interesting thing here, the memory growth was from my collectionview, which was unable to fit the content I wanted (screenshots), I kept getting warnings about that, autolayout freaked out here as well and memory kept on growing. @StepanGeneralov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the height of the row for the cell.?

Also did you checked the data for this object for section 3?

```
CellModel *current = [[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.titleLabel.text = current.title;
cell.subtitleLabel.text = current.subTitle;
cell.icon.image = current.image;
```

Comment: Hey! I return 66; in heightForRowAtIndexPath, and it is set to be 66 in IB as well. This might as well be a height for cell issue, because after changing its value, I started some weird stuff happening.

Comment: @AdamGartner After changing height what is happening?

Comment: Turns out it was Autolayout probems. I was overriding heightforrowatindexpath, in combination with an apple cell but with custom properties and heights. Be careful with the heights kids, that wasted a good amount of hours for me. TLDR: Design a nice custom cell with autolayout properties, let apple sysdevs do the rest for you :)